# Yelp API : Retrieving reviews of a business

Tags: api, yelp

IS there any way I could retrieve all the reviews of a business Using the API ?

The sample response here just shows 3

```
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business
```

Answer (score 3):

In `v3` yelp has a reviews API and it returns only `three` reviews per business.

[Yelp Business Reviews v3](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_reviews)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, yelp restricts reviews access via APIs. With the V2.0, it is restricted to just one review snippet, which is also truncated after 40 chars.

An alternate that you could try is to use web scraping platforms such as scrapy. Again, the challenge here is that, yelp changes its layout pretty often just to make sure you don't scrape out their data and hence, your scripts will likely fail after sometime.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?